# Поиск наибольшей общей подстроки

Tags: javascript

Требуется разработать на языке JavaScript код, печатающий на консоль самую длинную общую подстроку всех переданных строк.

Если самая длинная общая подстрока является пустой строкой (например, не было передано ни одной строки или строки не имеют общих для всех символов), напечатать один перевод строки (пустую строку).

При существовании нескольких решений — напечатать одно решение (любое).

Пример:

```
$ node lcs.js ABCDEFZ WBCDXYZ
CD

$ node lcs.js 132 12332 12312
1

$ node lcs.js ZZZABXXX XXXYYYAB ABYYYZZZ
AB
```

Код моего скрипта:

```
function lcs(strings)
{
    let shortest = strings.reduce((a, b) => a.length <= b.length ? a : b);
    let maxlen = shortest.length;
    for (let len = maxlen; len >= 0; len--)
    {
        for (let start = 0; start <= maxlen - len; start++)
        {       
            let substr = shortest.substring(start, len);
            if (strings.every(elem => ~elem.indexOf(substr))) {return substr;}
        }
    }
    return '';
}

if (process.argv.length < 3)
    console.log('');
else
    console.log(lcs(process.argv.slice(2)));
```

Работает неправильно: когда передаю в качестве параметров следующие строки:

```
ABCQEFDEFGHIJ BCXEFGYZBCDEWEFGHU
```

Мой код в консоль печатает `D`, хотя это не наибольшая общая подстрока.

Советовали использовать регулярные выражения, но с ними не знаком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:
let substr = shortest.substring(start, start+len);